# how to update a value in database using jquery when a link is clicked in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to increment count field in database when a link is clicked in php file.
So, I've added the following jquery part to my .php file. But still, it doesn't work. Please help!

```
<body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" id="click">click here</a>
    <script>
    $(function ()
    {
       $('#click').click(function()
      {
            var request = $.ajax(
            {    
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "code.php"                               
            });
       });
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

code.php:

```
<?php
     $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sample");
     mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE e set count=(count+1) WHERE sid='1'");

     mysqli_close($connection);

 ?>
```

Comment: what doesn't work about it? is the db connection details right? have you loaded jquery? do you have any errors in your browser console? errors in your php logs? does your database have the table and columns set correctly?

Comment: also you are clicking a link, have you prevented the default action some where else or does you browser just go to google.com once the link is clicked

Answer (score 1):

You made a several mistakes in your code.

**Update**

You can send your SID input type text from ajax with `data` and you can get the value in your `php` file with the `$sid = $_POST['sid']`.

```
<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="click">click here</a>
<input type="text" value="" name="sid" id="sid">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){

       $('#click').click(function(event)
       {
            var sidvalue = $("#sid").val(); /*from here you get value of your sid input box*/ 
            event.preventDefault(); 
            var request = $.ajax(
            {    
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "code.php",
                 data: 'sid='+sidvalue , 
                 success: function() {
                    window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/';
                 }                               
            });
       });
});
</script>
```

After the ajax success response you can make redirect to your desire location.

**Code.php**

```
<?php
     $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sample");

     $sid = $_POST['sid']; // use this variable at anywhere you want. 

     mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE e set count=(count+1) WHERE sid='1'");
     mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
```

in `code.php` in `mysqli_close` you should use `$conn` not `$connection`.

Go with this code. It might help you. I have just tested all the things in localhost. This is working perfect.

Comment: Thankyou so much :)

Comment: Please let me know this. How can  I send a $sid variable from php part to jquery/ajax part and then to code.php.

Comment: means you want to send variable from your form? ok let me edit code.. and please accept answer if it is working for you.. it is also help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

use `preventDefault()` when click event is called.check jquery :

```
<body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" id="click">click here</a>
    <script>
    $(function ()
    {
       $('#click').click(function(e)
      {
            e.preventDefault();
            var request = $.ajax(
            {    
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "code.php"                               
            });
       });
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -3):

Redirect your link on ajax success. Like this -

```
<body>
<a href="javascript:;" id="click">click here</a>
<script>
$(function ()
{
   $('#click').click(function()
  {
        var request = $.ajax(
        {    
             type: "POST",
             url: "code.php",
             success: function(response){
                 window.location="http://www.google.com";
             }
        });
   });
}
</script>
```

Comment: what is the meaning of your answer. read question first he want to update his table not want to redirect.